# Restoring fragment state with static variables

Tags: android, android-fragments

Usually fragment states are saved using `onSaveInstanceState()` and restored with `onViewStateRestored()` or by using a state instance fragment. However I noticed I can save fragment variable data by declaring the variables static. Obviously this won't work with view components but for primitives it seems to work fine. I wanted to know whether this static data is guaranteed to be preserved without saving it in `onSaveInstanceState()`.

Comment: Please. Just don't. Don't save state with static variables. Don't use static variables unless *really* necessary.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Care to elaborate on this?

Comment: This leads to really bad, hard to maintain and untestable code. If you have some time, watch the [Clean Code Talks](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL693EFD059797C21E)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not guaranteed.

When for example Android decides to kill your process,  the onSaveInstanceState() is called and the bundle will be available when you get back to your app as savedInstanceState, however all of the static variables will lose their values when your app gets killed. This applies to all of the static variables.